# How to index Kafka topic key value as a field using logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, logstash-configuration, kafka-topic

I would like to know to include Kafka topic key value along with the message as a separate field for indexing in Elasticsearch using Logstash .. the Kafka 'topic' weather contains the following messages as key value pairs:

BOSTON:99 
BOSTON:89 
NYC:75 
NYC:85

I am using the following Logstash configuration to do indexing:

```
input {
    kafka { 
    bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
    topics => ["weather"]
    }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      index => "weather"
      workers => 1
    }
}
```

However, only values are getting indexed, but not the key. The index looks like this:

```
 {
    "_index" : "weather",
    "_type" : "doc",
    "_id" : "48cGgXMBtkZlibwHwyWW",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "message" : "99",
      "@timestamp" : "2020-07-24T13:32:50.820Z",
      "@version" : "1"
    }
  {
    "_index" : "weather",
    "_type" : "doc",
    "_id" : "48cGgXMBtkZlibwHwyWW",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "message" : "89",
      "@timestamp" : "2020-07-24T13:32:50.820Z",
      "@version" : "1"
    }
```

I also need to have the city name (key of the topic) in the index. Once I have both, the end goal is to do different types of visualization in Kibana for each city's weather.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to enable the `decorate_events` option in your kafka input to get the [metadata fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html#_metadata_fields) from kafka, one of them is the key, then you will need to use a mutate filter to add the key metadata field to another field in your document (metadata fields are not sent to elasticsearch).

Answer (score 1):

```
input {
    kafka { 
    bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
    topics => ["weather"]
    decorate_events => true         (!!!)
    }
}
filter {
    mutate {
        add_field => {
            "key" => %{[@metadata][kafka][key]}" (!!!)
        }
    }
}
output {
elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "weather"
    workers => 1
    }
}
```

ref : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html#_metadata_fields

1. decorate_events option set to 'true'
2. add 'add_field' filter

Answer (score 0):

I included this in the conf file and I am now able to see the key information:

```
filter {
        mutate {
          copy => { "[@metadata][kafka]" => "kafka" }
        }
}
```